# Issue with GLMM in glmmTMB

Tags: r, glmmtmb

I am trying to run the following model:

```
MP1 <- glmmTMB(Abundance ~ All_predator + Year + Location + Depth +
             (1 | Site/Site.Transect),
           data = plandat,
           family = "poisson")
```

but am getting this error:

```
Error in .Call("getParameterOrder", data, parameters, new.env(),
PACKAGE = DLL) : 
Incorrect number of arguments (3), expecting 4 for
'getParameterOrder'
```

Does anyone know what this issue might be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a binary-incompatibility problem as documented [here](https://github.com/glmmTMB/glmmTMB/issues/791). You should probably have seen a "Package version inconsistency detected" message telling you to re-install glmmTMB from source. Depending on the release sequence of  TMB and glmmTMB on CRAN, updating from CRAN as usual might work; otherwise you need to re-install from source (see `?glmmTMB::reinstalling`).