# Template model builder - TMB - 'getParameterOrder' error

Tags: glmmtmb, tmb

I have been running models in TMB v1.7.15 without issue but when using newer versions of TMB I get the following error with the same models.

"Incorrect number of arguments (4), expecting 3 for 'getParameterOrder'"

Similar posts have been made about glmmTMB [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71913002/issue-with-glmm-in-glmmtmb) and point to  binary-incompatibility issues but I am just using TMB not glmmTMB. I have tried different verisons of R studio and on R studio Pro and get the same error